# Accessing the list of Controllers/Actions in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, controller, action

We know that behind the scenes, the ASP.NET MVC framework will use reflection to determine  what controllers/actions are available to be executed, based on which classes derive from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and, of those classes, which methods return an `ActionResult` object.

To my question - is it possible to access this list of controllers/actions from within my MVC application?

(I could do it myself, by using reflection on the current assembly, but if the list has already been built by ASP.NET MVC, I'd rather re-use that effort than re-invent the wheel myself.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TController)).GetCanonicalActions()` will return a collection of ActionDescriptor objects showing all the actions on the controller.  It's not smart enough to understand things like selection attributes or naming attributes, so not every action it returns is guaranteed to be web-callable.  But if you need to execute the actions directly, you can call ActionDescriptor.Execute() on any action of interest to you.

Answer (score 6):

This is done in an `internal` class in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly called `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache`.

By the way, action methods are not required to return `ActionResult`. They can return `void` happily, for instance.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying then what consitutes an action on a controller.  Any public method on a controller can be seen as an action I believe.

Comment: Yeah. Unless explicitly declared as `[NonAction]`, of course.