# Creat a list of links from controller actions ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, hyperlink

Is there a way to make a list of links for each action in controller instead of having to add

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "Index", "Home")%></li>
```

for each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is.

You can either return a SelectList of key value pairs that you can render as anchor tags.

Or you can create a model in the, and this is not the best place for it, controller and return it to the view which you can then itterate through.

```
public class myAnchorList
{
  public string text {get;set;}
  public string controller {get;set;}
  public string action {get;set;}
}
```

then in your code create a `List<myAnchorList>`.

```
List<myAnchorList> Anchors = new List<myAnchorList>();
```

Fill the list with data and return.

```
return View(Anchors).
```

if you are already passing over a model then you need to add this list into the model you are returning.

Make sense?  if not post a comment and i'll try to explain further.

**Edit**

Let me complete the picture now that i have a little more time.

On the client side you'd have this untested code;

```
<ul>
  <% foreach(myAnchorList item in Model.Anchors){ %>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink(item.text, item.action, item.controller)%></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: does the List<myAnchorList> Anchors = new List<myAnchorList>(); and return View(Anchors) go inside of the same action ? 

public ActionResult Index()
        {

}

I get an error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Anchors' and no extension method 'Anchors'

Comment: myAnchorList is a class and the Anchors is the name of the generic list of type myAnchorList.  So you need to place myAnchorList in a namespace your code has access to.  then you pass the list to the view and the view will need access to the namespace as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [griegs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563809/creat-a-list-of-links-from-controller-actions-asp-net-mvc/1563954#1563954), it might be helpful to construct the list of controller actions via reflection.  In which case you might want to look at:

```
new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TController)).GetCanonicalActions()
```

Credit for this answer goes to: [Accessing the list of Controllers/Actions in an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790464/accessing-the-list-of-controllers-actions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)